# HttpClient post doesn't return expected type

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

My backend is sending data in the format of a map:

```
{
   "key1": ["value1", "value2"],
   "key2": ["value3"]
}
```

I use HttpClient.post to get the data. The data returns fine, but when I try to do data.get I got an error

```
this.http.post<Map<string, string[]>>(url, body).toPromise()
  .then((data: Map<string, string[]>) => {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data instanceof Map); // false
    data.get('key1')                  // TypeError data.get is not a function
  });
```

Comment: what did you get from `console.log(data)`?

Comment: @KienNguyen this is what it logs: `{ key1: Array(2), key2: Array(1) }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data returned from the network request will be a plain object, not a `Map`.

You can convert it to a `Map` though. `Map` takes an array of key-value pairs, so you can use `Object.entries`:

```
this.http.post<Record<string, string[]>>(url, body).toPromise()
  .then((data) => {
    const dataMap = new Map(Object.entries(data))
    dataMap.get('key1')
  });
```

Comment: minor improvement: you could specify the type on http.post like so: `this.http.post<Record<string, string[]>>(...)`

Comment: @SteveHolgado What does the <T> in the post call do then? I thought it would cast it or something

Comment: @matchifang This is the response type that you expect but it is just a build-time check so it is not guaranteed that this is what you will get. See docs here: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using Promise. Use the observable, since it is better to debug and has more featurs.

The http builds a raw JSON object, that you only can map to an object with fields. Not methods. Map is not a Model like Object. it is a "functional object". Also constructors wont be triggered

Wich means, even though you say it should be a map it is in fact a JSON object wich has no methods.

For this reason you should pipe + map the data to a Map.

```js
this.http.post<object>(url, body)
.pipe( map(jsonObject => {
          const map = new Map<string, string[]>();
          for (const value in jsonObject) {
            map.set(value, jsonObject[value]);
          }
          return map;
        })
      ).subscribe(
        (data: Map<string, string[]>) => {
          console.log(data);
          console.log(data instanceof Map); // true
          data.get("key1");
        },
        error => console.log(error.error)
      );
```